# MIUI dial pad is not working

Tags: miui, sony-xperia-p

Recently  I have installed MIUI on my Xperia p. Everything is working fine except the dial pad. When I open the dial pad it automatically disappeared showing **UNFORTUNATELY DIAL PAD HAS STOPPED WORKING**. How can I resolve it??

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the ROM. Try installing a different ROM.

Comment: Is it official MIUI or a port? Is there a known bug list? Can you reinstall the apk? Would you consider another dialler, the stock kitkat one is pretty great (though you need to sideload a lot to get it) and there are lots of other ones.

Comment: @RossC it is an unofficial rom. Is there any way to install these firmware in clockwork mod?